# IRC program not printing last message

Tags: c, linux, websocket, irc, berkeley-sockets

I had a function that would receive data from an IRC server in 512-byte chunks and print it to the terminal window, it went like this:

```
int mainLoop(redchan_t *redchan)
{
    int socketDescriptor = redchan->socketDescriptor, i, bytesReceived;
    char workingBuffer[RECVBUFF] = {[0 ... RECVBUFF - 2] = '0', '\0'};

    puts("Recieving data...");

    do
    {
        if ((bytesReceived = recv(
                socketDescriptor,
                workingBuffer,
                RECVBUFF,
                0)) == 0)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        for (i = 0; i < bytesReceived; ++i)
            printf("%c", workingBuffer[i]);
    }
    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

But I wanted to make it more orthogonal so I took out the call to recv and put it in its own routine which looks like this:

```
int redchanRecv(redchan_t *redchan, int size, char *buffer)
{
    int totalBytes = 0, bytesReceived;

    while (totalBytes < size)
    {
        if ((bytesReceived = recv(
                        redchan->socketDescriptor,
                        buffer + totalBytes,
                        size - totalBytes,
                        0)) <= 0)
            cleanup_redchan(redchan, serverInfo);
        totalBytes += bytesReceived;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would then just call redchanRecv() in each iteration of my main loop and then print the buffer.
But when I run it, it prints out almost everything, except for one line.
That last line never makes it to the terminal (does it even make it into the buffer?).
I really feel like I'm making a rookie mistake but hell if I can see it.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdout` is line-buffered by default in your system, add a `fflush(stdout)` call to have your last line printed.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think all of the newlines I need come right from the server seeing as RFC1459 states that all IRC messages are terminated with \r\n.
I did try fflush but no dice.

Comment: @Red  but are you sure you (your program) receive all the new lines?

Comment: It's supposed to (well, it did, at least), but I've gone and borked something when I changed it.